# python matplotlib ax.get_xticks() doesn't get current xtick location

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run the attached code. On figure, ticks are labed from 0 to 1 by a step of 0.2, but I get -0.2 to 1.2 by running ax.get_xticks(). This is a bug, isn't it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ion()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.get_xticks()
ax.plot([-0.05, 1.06], [0.4, 0.5])
ax.get_xticks()
```

I expected to get array([0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1.]) other than array([-0.2,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ,  1.2])

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug.  Plotting just outside of the default 0 to 1 range in the x axis will cause the additional ticks to be added in order to rescale the axis to accommodate the new data range.  However, they are not displayed because they are outside of the `xlim` bounds.

You can see this by setting the ticks and xlim manually:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ion()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([-0.05, 1.06], [0.4, 0.5])
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks([-100.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 100.0])
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
```

To get which `xticks` are shown you can use:

```
x0, x1 = ax.get_xlim()
visible_ticks = [t for t in ax.get_xticks() if t>=x0 and t<=x1]
```

Comment: alright, I have to reset xtick locations when I relabel ticks. I found that my data are outside of the default 0 to 1. However, I still think it would be better if ax.get_ticks returns the same tick locations as ones on the figures, which might be more convinient for us. Thanks

Comment: I added a snippet to get the visible xtick locations.  I think you are correct.  You really shouldn't need to check if the xticks are within the xlim bounds to see if they are visible.